# Get execution for given date

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

Here's some code I have, which fetches the executions from a state machine which started on a given date:

```py
step_function_client = boto3.client("stepfunctions")
all_executions = step_function_client.list_executions(stateMachineArn=ARN)["executions"]
executions = [
    i
    for i in all_executions
    if i["startDate"].date() == execution_date.date()
]
```

However, it seems inefficient to list *all* executions and then filter them. Is there no way to filter the executions without pulling all of them from AWS?

Comment: Probably not, no.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to enable CloudWatch logg for state machine and then use CloudWatch Logs Insights to query and find executions based on date range.